# Getting python to run an application when the application needs an input file

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\michael\\Desktop\\Test\\pdftotext'])
```

pdftotext is the application that will run if I use this ^ code. This works fine, however, I'm trying to find a way to run pdftotext that includes the pdf's file name which pdftotext uses to convert it into a text file.

Note this is NOT a question about pdftotext.

When I use cmd in windows to run this I simply type **pdftotext *fileName*.pdf** and it converts the pdf file into a text file, no problem. Now I want to do something equivalent with Python.

I changed it to this, but it doesn't work. I'm told "The system cannot find the file specified" and I've put pdftotext in the src file along with filename.pdf

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\michael\\Desktop\\Test\\pdftotext', 'filename.pdf'])
```

Comment: Use a `r"raw\string"` to ensure you don't make mistakes in the string literal such as using `"\m"` instead of `"\\m"`. Fortunately `"\m"` isn't a special character.

Comment: Also you're depending on "filename.pdf" being in the working directory. That depends on how the script is run. You may instead need the absolute path to the file, or a path that's relative to the script's directory. Novice programmers often mistakenly assume that the script directory and the working directory are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) takes an iterable where the first item is the executable and the following are switches and parameters.

This means you need to change the above to this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\michael\\Desktop\\Test\\pdftotext', 'filename.pdf'])
```